# Bash script tail not matching a pattern

Tags: bash, ubuntu, service

I've written a bash script and I use a tail/grep expression to wait for a process to arrive at a certain point, so I then start another processes. I do it with:

```
tail -n0 -f ${FILE_TO_WATCH} | grep -qe ${SEARCH_PATTERN}
```

The the log file defined as FILE_TO_WATCH (with its full name), sooner or later, always gets the SEARCH_PATTERN.
When I use the script with `./my_script` it always works: The pattern is found and the script continues. But when I've tried to use the script as a service, the pattern is not found and I see with a `ps` that the script is waiting the tail to exit, even when I see the pattern in the log file...

About the service, I've defined my user to exceute it...
So I don't know what happen with it. What is so different from an execution from the command line or from a service than can cause this effect?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you want `tail -n0 -f`? This trashes all existing lines in the file and only prints lines that were added to  the file *after* you started `tail`. Maybe this is the problem. Have you tried `tail -f ${FILE_TO_WATCH} | grep -qe ${SEARCH_PATTERN}` (without `-n0`)?

Comment: Well, `-n0` is what I need. I look into a log file that may contain the pattern from previous executions, so I want to find the pattern just after `tail` starts. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I just wanted to make sure. Then maybe the problem is the unquoted variables. What is your search pattern? If it contains a `*` or `[...]` (very likely for regexes) the unquoted pattern might be replaced with a matching filename before grep even sees it. This could also explain why it worked in a script but not in a service, since a service usually has a different working directory.

Comment: If I understand well, you think that it could be a problem of the replacement of the variables for their values. I've modified the script and on the `tail` I have now this:  `tail -n0 -f "/home/ramon/croatd.log" | grep -qe "SYNCHRONIZED"`. It still continues the same, it work from the command line and it does not if run it as a service.

Comment: If I get the ps related to this, I get: `ramon      11279   11270 37 00:50 ?        00:01:10 ./croatd --data-dir /home/ramon/.croat
ramon      11282   11270 42 00:50 ?        00:01:19 tail -n0 -f /home/ramon/croatd.log
ramon      12378     862  0 00:54 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto croatd
`